# Outlook Push Notifications REST API - How to protect the Notification URL?

Tags: azure, outlook, webhooks, office365api, outlook-restapi

I have implemented an integration with Outlook API. We are using the Notifications Rest API to get the notifications on any changes on the users mailbox.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/notify-rest-operations

As part of this we need to provide Notification URL (of client application). This is where Outlook will push the notifications.

Question: How do we protect this Notification URl from abuse?

It would have been better if Microsoft sent some basic auth along with Notification URl.

Please help on what is the best practice to protect this webhook from DOS attacks.

Comment: How to integrate outlook API to Asp.Net Core Web API project ?

Answer (score 0):

This is what the `ClientState` property is for. You can pass a secret in there and ignore any notifications which do not include the secret.